# Heritage : CRUD Operations in EntityFramework using DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to realize my CRUD operations in Entity Framework using DbContext

i have a class called "offreLocation" inherit from a supper class called "publication"

i do not get any error, but after clicking in the create button, i still have the create view although i specified a redirection to the list view after creating.

here my Create Function

```
  // POST: /OffreLocation/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOffreLocation(OffreLocation offreLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            db.PublicationSet.Add(offreLocation);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ListOffreLocation");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My Create view :

```
@model COM.MENNILIK.Models.OffreLocation

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "CreateOffreLocation";
}

<h2 style="text-align:center">Nouvelle offre de location </h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_ID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_ID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_ID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_Statut, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_Statut)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_Statut)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_Meublee, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_Meublee)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_Meublee)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_Descriptif, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_Descriptif)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_Descriptif)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_ContactParAgence, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_ContactParAgence)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_ContactParAgence)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_Maps_Latitude, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_Maps_Latitude)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_Maps_Latitude)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publication_Maps_Longitude, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publication_Maps_Longitude)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publication_Maps_Longitude)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_TypeLog, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_TypeLog)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_TypeLog)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Sante, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Sante)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Sante)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Loyer, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Loyer)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Loyer)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_DateDisponibilite, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_DateDisponibilite)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_DateDisponibilite)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Superficie, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Superficie)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_Superficie)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_NbreChambre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_NbreChambre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_NbreChambre)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OffreLocation_NbrePieces, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OffreLocation_NbrePieces)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OffreLocation_NbrePieces)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ListOffreLocation")
</div>
```

for more precision here my Model Container

```
public partial class Model1Container : DbContext
{
    public Model1Container()
        : base("name=Model1Container")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Utilisateur> UtilisateurSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Abonnement> AbonnementSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AbonnementHistorique> AbonnementHistoriqueSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ColocataireIdeal> ColocataireIdealSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Publication> PublicationSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Quartier> QuartierSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ville> VilleSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegionProvince> RegionProvinceSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Photo> PhotoSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MessageLocation> MessageLocationSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MessageColocation> MessageColocationSet { get; set; }
}
```

"publication" Model

```
    public partial class Publication
{
    public Publication()
    {
        this.Photo = new HashSet<Photo>();
    }

    public int Publication_ID { get; set; }
    public string Publication_Statut { get; set; }
    public bool Publication_Meublee { get; set; }
    public string Publication_Descriptif { get; set; }
    public bool Publication_ContactParAgence { get; set; }
    public double Publication_Maps_Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Publication_Maps_Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual Quartier Quartier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photo { get; set; }
}
```

"offreLocation" Model

```
 public partial class OffreLocation : Publication
{
    public OffreLocation()
    {
        this.Locataire = new HashSet<Locataire>();
        this.DemandeLocation = new HashSet<DemandeLocation>();
        this.DemandeLocation1 = new HashSet<DemandeLocation>();
        this.DemandeLocation2 = new HashSet<DemandeLocation>();
        this.DemandeLocation3 = new HashSet<DemandeLocation>();
    }

    public string OffreLocation_TypeLog { get; set; }
    public string OffreLocation_Sante { get; set; }
    public double OffreLocation_Loyer { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OffreLocation_DateDisponibilite { get; set; }
    public double OffreLocation_Superficie { get; set; }
    public short OffreLocation_NbreChambre { get; set; }
    public short OffreLocation_NbrePieces { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Locataire> Locataire { get; set; }
    public virtual Proprietaire Proprietaire { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DemandeLocation> DemandeLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DemandeLocation> DemandeLocation1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DemandeLocation> DemandeLocation2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DemandeLocation> DemandeLocation3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is your Action `ListOffreLocation`?

Comment: my action ListOffreLocation works very well, i can get my list from the database :  // GET: /OffreLocation/
        public ActionResult ListOffreLocation()
        {
            return View(db.PublicationSet.OfType<OffreLocation>().ToList());
        }

Comment: Is it in the same controller?

Comment: _"i do not get any error"_ - because you catch and silently swallow the exception. Change to `catch (Exception ex)`, put a breakpoint and search the web for the exception message.

Comment: plz show the implementation of your "ListOffreLocation" action. Otherwise, it's **Exception** that's making you stay on the same view

Comment: I second CodeCaster's comments.  It seems like you're exception handling routine, while graceful, is hiding the actual error here.  You might be better off during development to comment out the try catch here and see what exception the "Yellow Screen" shows you.  Or as CodeCaster mentions read the exception while debugging.

Comment: `remove try cache block , then run your application. ` cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are getting an Exception at either of these 2 lines:

```
db.PublicationSet.Add(offreLocation);
db.SaveChanges();
```

which takes you to the `catch` block. which again returns the same view.

```
catch
{
    return View();
}
```

Try debugging your code. Place `breakpoint` at these 2 lines. and find what is causing it to throw exception. (It's most probably due to some Database related issue, wrong data etc.)

Comment: It's OK now, i caught the exception : it's a foreign key a problem, i didn't specify a value for a relation (1..*) field